# Creating a reflink with Java

Tags: java, java-io

[`java.nio.Files.createSymbolicLink`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) is used to create a symbolic link. Can I create a [reflink](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/unix_links.html) via the SDK (akin to [cp --reflink=[WHEN]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)), or do I need to exec out to the underlying OS?

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer GC. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind: most of the Java APIs are meant to be used "write once, run everywhere". So they focus on supporting what works on a large number of operating systems. Maybe that initial motivation isn't that important any more in our daily work, but it still represents an essential paradigm framing the Java language.

Therefore, not surprisingly, the built-in standard class only knows about the the (relatively) generic link and soft links.

Coming from there, these (relatively) new ref links (which only exist on highly specialized *file* systems) aren't supported. And I doubt they ever will be.

So, yes, you are left with either calling a system command or searching for a 3rd party library (the later one would be off topic here).

Comment: You have an unmistakable style  : your answers are fine and you are a real poet my dear !

Comment: reflinks are arguably no longer that rare since macOS APFS's and windows server ReFS's adoption of it. An improvement proposal by a Java team member should be enough to make it a thing.

Comment: You are always free to get a corresponding process started.

Comment: @GhostCat guess what, a fresh PR for Linux reflink just got merged. https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/9486, as https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/da596182a494a36d37030f18328e52e525fc3565